# Telnet by using Expect ends the connection without any notification

Tags: shell, virtual-machine, expect

Some Background:
    Using one machine installed VMA(vSphere Management Assistant) to try to telnet one IP to modify some config of the VM by scripting.

1.First of all I have to say I can telnet the IP I want to connect manually, but when I try to telnet via shell script, it keep failed and receive `Connection closed by foreign host`.

2.Then I change to use Expect, and do the same thing, I can successfully connect to the IP but the script ran in the middle, session seems time out, please see my logs in the following:

```
vi-admin@localhost:~>
vi-admin@localhost:~> more telnetTest.sh

#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
set ip 10.222.99.108
set port 7001
set user "admin"
set password ""

spawn telnet $ip $port
expect "'^]'."
send "\r";
expect {
    "login:" {
        send "$user\r"
        expect "Password:"
        send "$password\r"
        expect "FGVM*"
        send "config system interface\r"
    }
    "FGVM*#" { send "config system interface\r"}

}
vi-admin@localhost:~> expect telnetTest.sh
spawn telnet 10.222.99.108 7001
Trying 10.222.99.108...
Connected to 10.222.99.108.
Escape character is '^]'.


FGVM02AO20310001 #
FGVM02AO20310001 # \777\774%vi-admin@localhost:~>
vi-admin@localhost:~>
```

Comment: You just have to send only one command `"config system interface` alone ?.

Comment: No, just use one command for testing, since it would not get there even when I typed more commands.

Comment: Add `expect "FGVM*#"` after sending `config system interface` command.